# Morphisms of sheaves on a covering

Tags: sheaf-theory

I have encountered the following situation: Suppose we are given a site C admitting a final object $X$, together with a covering $\tilde{X}\to X$ by a single object. Now I have a sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on $X$, such that $\mathcal{F}|_{\tilde{X}}$ is a constant sheaf associated to an abelian group $A$, in symbols $\mathcal{F}|_{\tilde{X}}=\underline{A}$.

I would now like to understand morphisms $Hom(\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G})$ into some abelian sheaf $\mathcal{G}$. Now this is where my confusion is:

1. We may consider the slice category $C/\tilde{X}$ which is a base for the site C. Then, the restriction functor $\mathcal{G} \mapsto \mathcal{G}|_{\tilde{X}}$ induces an equivalence of categories between the categories of sheaves on $C$, and the categories of sheaves on $C/\tilde{X}$. With this reasoning,
   $Hom(\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G})=Hom(\mathcal{F}|_{\tilde{X}},\mathcal{G}|_{\tilde{X}})=Hom(\underline{A},\mathcal{G}|_{\tilde{X}})=Hom(A,\mathcal{G}(\tilde{X}))$.
2. On the other hand, we have the sheaf $\mathscr{H}\kern -.90pt om(\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G})$. Using this, we may compute
   $Hom(\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G})
   =\mathscr{H}\kern -.90pt om(\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G})(X)
   =\ker\left(\mathscr{H}\kern -.90pt om(\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G})(\tilde{X})\to\mathscr{H}\kern -.90pt om(\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G})(\tilde{X}\times_{X}\tilde{X})\right)
   =\ker\left(Hom(\mathcal{F}|_{\tilde{X}},\mathcal{G}|_{\tilde{X}})(\tilde{X})\to Hom(\mathcal{F}|_{\tilde{X}\times_{X}\tilde{X}},\mathcal{G}|_{\tilde{X}\times_{X}\tilde{X}})\right)
   =\ker\left(Hom(\underline{A}|_{\tilde{X}},\mathcal{G}|_{\tilde{X}})\to Hom(\underline{A}|_{\tilde{X}\times_{X}\tilde{X}},\mathcal{G}|_{\tilde{X}\times_{X}\tilde{X}})\right)
   =\ker\left(Hom(A,\mathcal{G}(\tilde{X}))\to Hom(A,\mathcal{G}(\tilde{X}\times_{X}\tilde{X}))\right)
   =Hom(A,\ker\left(\mathcal{G}(\tilde{X}))\to \mathcal{G}(\tilde{X}\times_{X}\tilde{X}) \right))
   =Hom(A,\mathcal{G}(X))$.

But in general $Hom(A,\mathcal{G}(\tilde{X}))\neq Hom(A,\mathcal{G}(X))$. Something must have gone wrong: Where is my mistake?

Remark: The specific situation I am thinking about is in Proposition 6.10 here: https://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/scholze/pAdicHodgeTheory.pdf

Comment: I don't understand why do you think that $\mathcal{G}\mapsto \mathcal{G}|_{\tilde{X}}$ is an equivalence of category between the category of sheaves on $C$ and the category of sheaves on $C/\tilde{X}$. For example, take $X = S^1$ and $\tilde{X} = (0,1) \sqcup (0,1)$ and a cover $\tilde{X}\to X$. Now the categories of sheaves on $S^1$ is clearly not equivalent to the category of sheaves on $(0,1) \sqcup (0,1)$.

Comment: I guess then my confusion comes from the notion of a basis of a site? I thought that every open $U\in C$ has a covering by an object in the localised site $C/\tilde{X}$, namely $U\times \tilde{X}\to U$. Maybe is my misconception that $C/\tilde{X}$ is not a full subcategory of $C$ in general, thus it is not a basis?

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand your comment. Yes, for every open $U\in C$, $U\times\tilde{X}\to U$ is a covering of $U$. Also, what is your definition of basis of a site ?

Comment: My definition for a basis of a site is: A full subcategory $B$ of $C$ such that for every open $U\in C$, there exists a covering $\mathfrak{U}$ such that for each $V\in\mathfrak{U}$, $V\in B$.

Comment: @Roland What is the site you are considering in your first comment?

Comment: Just the site coming from the topology of $S^1$, that is the category such that objects are disjoint unions $\coprod U_i$ where $U_i$ are open subsets of $S^1$.

Comment: Sorry, I realize that I didn't answer your previous question. Yes $C / \tilde{X}$ is not necessarily a full subcategory of $C/X$ but that doesn't mean that $\tilde{X}$ is not a covering.